# write to TraceListener from multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, debugging, trace

I have a custom TraceListener and two threads. Trace messages only come through from the first thread and the second thread's Trace.Write() messages do not come through. I've tried using a single, global TraceListener that both threads have access to, but the second thread still does not produce any output.

How do I implement this so that both threads write to the same Trace output? If the trace listener utilizes locking appropriately, is it possible to do?

```
void Initialize()
{
    Trace.Listeners.Add(App.CustomTraceListener);
    Trace.Write("test?"); // this produces output
    var start = new ThreadStart(Run);
    var thread = new Thread(start);
    thread.Start();
}

void Run()
{
    while(true)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      Trace.Write("hello from second thread"); // this does not produce anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Trace.Flush();` after `thread.Start();` or inside `Run();` and you'll see the output.

Answer (score 3):

Also adding `Trace.AutoFlush = true` also works out well.